# .htaccess redirection spesific url to other directory

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

How to redirect this:

URI: `http://www.example.com/blog` but `/blog` isn't inside root domain subdirectory but in another directory

So when people type `www.example.com/blog` it loads other directory instead of subdirectory of root domain.

Comment: To where do you want to redirect `www.abc.com/blog` ?

Comment: what have you tried? What has worked and what has failed? What documentation have you read about Apache Mod Rewrite?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the other 438 questions on this exact topic, on Stack Overflow before asking your own? If so, what makes your situation different from all the others?

Answer (score 0):

This is best handled by the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive

```
Alias /blog /path/to/blog/outside/root
```

Unfortunately, this does not work in an .htaccess file, only in the main configuration. If you don't have access to the main config files and need to do this in .htaccess, you may resort to a [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^/blog(.*)$ /path/to/blog/outside/root$1 [L]
```